# Как в Swift объединить в один массив два разных класса?

Tags: swift

Начал изучать Swift не та давно. Дали учебное задание. Есть два класса People и Marsianin и их наследники. Нужно объединить в один массив все объекты с двух РАЗНЫХ классов потом вывести в цикле тип объектов и выводить свойства и вызывать методы. Как это сделать? Вот код:

```
class People {
    var name = "Jack"
    var growth = 180
    var weight = 70
    var gender = "M"

    func Say()  {
        print("People with name \(name) say Hi!")
    }
}
class Cook : People {
    override func Say() {
        name = "Bob"
        print("Cook with name \(name) say Hi!")
    }
}

class Manager : People {
    override func Say() {
        name = "Nelly"
        print("Manager with name \(name) say Hi!")
    }
}

class Fighter : People {
    override func Say() {
        name = "Braun"
        print("Fighter with name \(name) say Hi!")
    }
}

class Programer : People {
    var skill = "Bog"

    override func Say() {
        let people = People()
        people.Say()
        print("Bill with name \(name) say Hi!")
    }
}

class Marsianin {
    var name = "Djuliy"
    var growth = 180
    var weight = 70
    var gender = "M"

    func Say()  {
        print("People with name \(name) say Hi!")
    }
}
class Zemliynen : Marsianin {
    override func Say() {
        name = "Bobin"
        print("Cook with name \(name) say Hi!")
    }
}

class Lunanen : Marsianin {
    override func Say() {
        name = "Mallyn"
        print("Manager with name \(name) say Hi!")
    }
}

var cook = Cook()
var manager = Manager()
var fighter = Fighter()
var programer = Programer()

cook.growth = 172
cook.weight = 63
cook.gender = "M"

manager.growth = 170
manager.weight = 60
manager.gender = "W"

fighter.growth = 180
fighter.weight = 110
fighter.gender = "M"

programer.growth = 175
programer.weight = 60
programer.gender = "M"
programer.skill = "Super Bog"

var marsianin = Marsianin()
var zemliynen = Zemliynen()
var lunanen = Lunanen()

var workingEndMarsianin = Array<AnyObject>()
workingEndMarsianin = [cook, manager, fighter, programer, marsianin, zemliynen, lunanen]

for i in workingEndMarsianin {
    print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы вызвать метод `Say()` внутри цикла, все объекты массива `workingEndMarsianin` должны иметь имплементацию метода `Say()`. Это возможно сделать с помощью протокола или наследования.

В случае с протоколом это было бы так:

```
protocol Speaker {
    func Say()
}

protocol BodyMetrics {
    var name: String {get}
    var growth: Int {get}
    var weight: Int {get}
    var gender: String {get}
}

protocol SpeakerWithBodyMetrics: Speaker, BodyMetrics {}
```

Классы `People` и `Marsianin` соответствуют протоколу SpeakerWithBodyMetrics

```
extension People: SpeakerWithBodyMetrics {}

extension Marsianin: SpeakerWithBodyMetrics {}
```

Тк все объекты одного протокола, мы можем иметь их в одном массиве

```
let speakers: [SpeakerWithBodyMetrics] = [cook, manager, fighter, programer, marsianin, zemliynen, lunanen]

for speaker in speakers {
    print(speaker.name)
    speaker.Say()
}
```